# How can I avoid raw types for a recursively defined list of lists?

Tags: java, arrays, list, recursion

In Java, I'm building an n-dimensional data structure of outputs of a function of the form `f(x_1,...,x_n)->y`, which I then convert to JSON and pass back to a client, where it is processed. Since the depth of the data structure depends on the number of input arguments to the evaluated function (it is also `n` dimensional), I'm generating the data structure using a recursive functions which is passed a list of parameters and generates a list of lists if it is passed more than two parameters, or a list of doubles if it is only passed a single parameters. The method for generating the list looks something like this:

```
static private List buildList(List<String> parameters){
    if(parameters.size() > 1){
        List<List> returnList = new arrayList<List>;
        //call buildList to generate contents of returnList;
        return returnList;
    } else {
        List<Double> returnList = array of values generated by another method
        return returnList;
    }
}
```

This method is called by another method, which takes the output list, converts it to JSON, and adds it to the response object.

My problem with this approach is that, since I don't know the dimensionality of my data structure until runtime, I'm not sure how to define my function so that I'm not handling and returning raw data types like `List` and `List<List>`. Ideally, it seems like I should type the return as something like `List<List<List<Double>>>` for a three dimensional data structure, but I'm not sure how to set up my code to do this. I don't code a lot of Java, so type safety is a relatively unfamiliar concept for me, but I'm under the impression that use of raw types is generally frowned upon in the wonderful world of Java.

Is there a best practices way of avoiding the use of raw types in this sort of recursive pattern, or should I stick with my current approach?

Comment: You'll have to use a `List<Object>`.

Answer (score 1):

The parent class of every object is the Object class. `<Object>` can keep anything held to it (`List<List<List<Double>>>`). Therefore everytime you declare a `List` make the type `Object` which is able to hold any object.

Answer (score 1):

Generics (the stuff between the "angle brackets") are used for compile-time type safety checking.

If you don't know the contents of the given list until the request, there's no point.

You can probably most easily type your list as `List<Object>`.

Also, side tip, assuming you're java 7 or higher, you can declare the impl more simply:

```
List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note the empty `<>` on `ArrayList`.  This means "per declared type".  Just makes your code slightly more succinct.

Comment: Note that `List<?>` is **not the same** as `List<Object>`. A `List<Object>` is a list of anything, a `List<?>` is a list of some specific unknown type. You cannot `add` to a `List<?>`.